# Securing access to folders

Tags: windows

I have a folder with all my documents. These documents are located on partition M of my hard drive. How can I secure these documents from access from other users except myself?
So that they cannot be accessed by another user on my windows installation nor by an other windows or Linux installation.

Comment: File permissions will go a long way. Anyone with physical access can get around them with the right tools however. Disk encryption will help protect against those tools. There is no 100% solution; layers of complexity only add time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TrueCrypt. Will only be able to read and accessed if you have the password. Also, with TrueCrypt you can encrypt certain folders, or the whole drive.

http://www.truecrypt.com